# Are questions about doing research related to academia?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question is rather straight forward. Are questions, related to doing research, related to academia? Academia is, after all, the main place where research is done and which often sets the standards of doing research. If not, what forum would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, as per our [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> This site is for *academics* of all levels—from aspiring graduate and professional students to senior researchers—as well as ***anyone in or interested in research-related or research-adjacent*** fields.

Note, however, that this is site is for questions about *process, customs, standards of behavior, etc.* in academia and/or research.

Just as a question on a user's particular field of academic study would be off-topic (e.g., a [question on mathematics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30712/question-1-really-very-difficul-question-for-me-i-tried-very-hard-but-i-could)), similarly a question on a user's particular field of research would be off-topic (e.g., a question on [how to find information about Netflix's global strategy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30998/strategic-issues-faced-by-netflix-evaluation-of-its-strategy-globally)).

Comment: But would we accept questions on non-academic research?  Say, a project in industry where the goal is to develop a product rather than to publish?  I'm not sure this community would be a good source of expertise on such questions.

Comment: @Nate as long as it's firmly in the "research" category and not straightforward product development then yes, I think we would.